# PHP session management with memcached

Tags: php, session, memcached

If there are many memcached or memcached servers to save PHP session , Does PHP save all the same sessions in all of the servers?

Example:
if PHP configured like this:

```
session.save_handler = memcache
session.save_path = "tcp://server1:11211,tcp://server2:11211,tcp://server3:11211"
```

And if we have:

```
$_SESSION['user_id']=123456;
```

Does this variable will be saved in server1, server2 & server3?

Comment: It's wrong save session in memcache! It's not guarantee the safety of data if you not update time of live when get data from memcache.

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of this , the session data is not important in my case.

Comment: I think, memcached do not share data with other memcache's servers. Because, it's for caching not for `sharing`